# why the outcome is helloworld123456?? instead of helloworld 1234567

Tags: c, strcat

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mystrcat(char* s1, const char* s2);

int main() {
    char s1[] = "helloworld";
    char s2[] = "1234567";

    printf("%s\n", mystrcat(s1,s2));
    return 0;
}

char* mystrcat(char* s1,const char* s2) {
    int idx=0;
    char *p=s1;

    while(s2[idx]) {
        s1[strlen(s1)] = s2[idx];
        idx++;
    }

    s1[strlen(s1)] = '\0';
    return p;
}
```

Comment: you should check how works strlen, it will search for `\0` so doing strlen in while won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size. You can't extend an array. And when you create your arrays:

```
char s1[]="helloworld";
char s2[]="1234567";
```

then they will have the size they are initialized with: `s1` will be `11` elements long, and `s2` will be `8` characters long.

So the first problem is that you attempt to add elements to `s1`, but it doesn't fit any more elements. You need to make sure it can hold space for *at least* `18` characters:

```
char s1[30]="helloworld";  // 30 should be well enough for this simple test
```

---

Then we come to the *second* problem, which happens when you do:

```
s1[strlen(s1)] = s2[idx];
```

This works only for the *first* appending to `s1`. That first assignment will overwrite the null-terminator, and after this the string in `s1` is no longer a null-terminated string and you can't use `strlen` to get its length.

You need to keep track of the `s1` position using a variable, similarly to what you do for `s2`.

---

However, once these issues are fixed, the output will *still* not be `helloworld 1234567`, because you don't add any space between the two strings.